# How to send a LocalBroadcast from adb shell?

Tags: android

I know how to send a broadcast from adb shell if a static receiver is declared in android manifest file. But is there a way to send a LocalBroadcast from adb shell?

I guess there is no way to achieve that. If that is true, how effectively can I test a LocalBroadcast? Should I delegate the broadcast intent to a handler whose behaviour can be tested in isolation?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> But is there a way to send a LocalBroadcast from adb shell?

No, because `LocalBroadcastManager` is an in-process event bus, and the shell is not in your process.

> how effectively can I test a LocalBroadcast?

Through a test suite, such as using instrumentation testing with JUnit. That runs in the same process as does the rest of your app code, and so it should be able to send local broadcasts.

> Should I delegate the broadcast intent to a handler whose behaviour can be tested in isolation?

That is probably a good idea.